# Binomial like multiplication of elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list

```
p = {0.10715, 0.08058, 0.00360, 0.00183}
```

how to implement function that does:

```
(p[[1]]*(1 - p[[2]])*(1 - p[[3]])*(1 - p[[4]])) + 
((1 - p[[1]])*p[[2]]*(1 - p[[3]])*(1 - p[[4]])) +
((1 - p[[1]])*(1 - p[[2]])*p[[3]]*(1 - p[[4]])) +
((1 - p[[1]])*(1 - p[[2]])*(1 - p[[3]])*p[[4]])
```

and  generalizes for any length of p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
p = {0.10715, 0.08058, 0.00360, 0.00183};
Table[If[p[[i]] != 1, (Times @@ ((1 - #) & /@ p) p[[i]]/(1 - p[[i]])), 1], {i, Length[p]}]

(*{0.0979816, 0.0715557, 0.00294985, 0.00149685}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

@DanielHuber 's answer is a direct way to go.  But with *Mathematica* you can have some really obtuse (but maybe compact and hopefully efficient) ways to get the same result.  Here is one that even works symbolically:

```
binoSum[p_]:=Table[i (-1)^(i - 1) SymmetricPolynomial[i, p], {i, Length[p]}] // Total

binoSum[{0.10715, 0.08058, 0.00360, 0.00183}]
(* 0.173984 *)

binomSum[{p1,p2,p3,p4}]//Expand
(* p1 + p2 - 2 p1 p2 + p3 - 2 p1 p3 - 2 p2 p3 + 3 p1 p2 p3 + p4 - 
   2 p1 p4 - 2 p2 p4 + 3 p1 p2 p4 - 2 p3 p4 + 3 p1 p3 p4 + 3 p2 p3 p4 - 
   4 p1 p2 p3 p4 *)
```

As a poor justification consider expanding the equation you gave:

```
p = {p1, p2, p3, p4};
(p[[1]]*(1 - p[[2]])*(1 - p[[3]])*(1 - p[[4]])) + 
((1 - p[[1]])*p[[2]]*(1 - p[[3]])*(1 - p[[4]])) +
((1 - p[[1]])*(1 - p[[2]])*p[[3]]*(1 - p[[4]])) +
((1 - p[[1]])*(1 - p[[2]])*(1 - p[[3]])*p[[4]])//Expand
(* p1 + p2 - 2 p1 p2 + p3 - 2 p1 p3 - 2 p2 p3 + 3 p1 p2 p3 + p4 - 
   2 p1 p4 - 2 p2 p4 + 3 p1 p2 p4 - 2 p3 p4 + 3 p1 p3 p4 + 3 p2 p3 p4 - 
   4 p1 p2 p3 p4 *)
```

What you've described is the probability of exactly one success among 4 independent Bernoulli distributions each with a (potentially) different probability of success.  (See [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93852/sum-of-bernoulli-variables-with-different-success-probabilities) for an example.)

If you are interested the probability of 0, 1, 2, 3,... successes at $n$ independent locations, then the brute force approach is as following:

```
n = 5; (* Number of independent locations *)
dist = TransformedDistribution[Sum[x[i], {i, n}], 
   Table[x[i] \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[p[i]], {i, n}]];
PDF[dist, y]
```

[image: PDF of sum of Bernoulli random variables]

If $n$ is large, then this becomes a bit cumbersome.  However, one can use a normal approximation with the mean and variance from this distribution:

```
Mean[dist]
(* p[1] + p[2] + p[3] + p[4] + p[5] *)
Variance[dist]
(* p[1] - p[1]^2 + p[2] - p[2]^2 + p[3] - p[3]^2 + p[4] - p[4]^2 + p[5] - p[5]^2 *)
```

Or more compactly:

```
Sum[p[i],{i,n}]
Sum[p[i](1-p[i]),{i,n}]
```

Comment: I find your symbolic solution interesting.  I learnt something new as i did not know about SymmetrucPolynomial. For large number of elements, this symbolic approach is not efficient. How would you go about increasing it's efficiency?

Comment: Could you add a bit more information such as (1) Is the objective to do something with the symbolic result or will there always be a numerical result?  (2) How large is large?

Comment: If you need a symbolic result and can assume that none of the elements are 1, then `Product[(1 - p[[i]]), {i, n}] Sum[p[[i]]/(1 - p[[i]]), {i, n}]` works pretty fast.  If there are 2 or more elements that are 1, then the sum is 0.

Comment: Thank you for your time; your new solution is fast. The elements of the list are always less than 1.

Comment: One more question from me:  The elements being considered: are they random variables for which one needs various moments (mean, variance, etc.) or are they just numbers?

Comment: They are probabilities  in 2d space but I have omitted the space coordinates in my question. Say we have "n" points, where n=Length[p] in my post. The purpose is to use the individual probabilities p[[i]] to determine the probability of a an event occurring at any of the n points. So if we compute the mean, it will be average number of points that this even has occurred. So what you are suggesting to me will be cool to have.

Comment: The equation that you presented is then the probability of exactly 1 event (assuming that the events are independent among the points in 2d space).  I'll add something about that to my answer.

Comment: Exactly. the equation in my question is for one event assuming independence.